Ricci tensor in locally Lorentz frame
In the book A Relativist's Toolkit by Eric Poisson, section 4.1.4, page $123$, it is written that in a local Lorentz frame at a point $P$:
$$\delta R_{\alpha \beta} \stackrel{*}{=} \delta\left(\Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha \beta, \mu}-\Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha \mu, \beta}\right)$$
I am not able to get it from the expression:
$$R_{ij} = \partial_k \Gamma^k{}_{ij} - \partial_j \Gamma^k{}_{ik} + \Gamma^k{}_{ij} \Gamma^m{}_{km} - \Gamma^k{}_{im} \Gamma^m{}_{jk}
$$
I will be glad if someone can help me in this.

In a local Lorentz frame all the Christoffel symbols are zero, though their derivatives are not, so your second equation simplifies considerably.


In normal coordinates centered at $p\in M$, the Christoffel symbols of the Levi-Civita connection
are equal to zero at $p$ and the metric is Minkowskian up to second order corrections i.e.
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\sigma}(0)=0 \quad g_{\mu\nu}(x)=\eta_{\mu\nu}+\mathcal{O}(|x|^2)
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
where we've used $x$ for the normal coordinates in a neighbourhood of $p\mapsto(0,0,0,0)$.
The general coordinate expression of the Riemann tensor is \begin{equation}
R^{\rho}{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} =
  \partial_{\mu}\Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\nu\sigma} -
  \partial_{\nu}\Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\mu\sigma} +
  \Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\mu\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\nu\sigma} -
  \Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\nu\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\sigma}
\tag{2a}\label{2a}
\end{equation}
Switching to normal coordinates, using \eqref{1} and neglecting higher order contributions yields
\begin{equation}
R^{\rho}{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} \overset{\ast}{=}
  \partial_{\mu}\Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\nu\sigma}
  -\partial_{\nu}\Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\mu\sigma}\tag{2b}\label{2b}
\end{equation}
Contracting \eqref{2b} yields the Ricci tensor
\begin{equation}
R_{\sigma\nu} \overset{\ast}{=}
  \partial_{\mu}\Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\nu\sigma}
  -\partial_{\nu}\Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\mu\sigma}\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}.
OP's equation is the variation of the Ricci tensor using the coordinate expression \eqref{3}.

References

A Relativist’s Toolkit:
The Mathematics of Black-Hole Mechanics, Eric Poisson. CUP, 2007. Page 123.

